# Implementing clustering in openDDS?

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I have built OpenDDS using C++. I'm using it for a real time application. I want to scale it to different nodes in distributed system.

So, is it possible to cluster OpenDDS?

Comment: With DCPS as wire protocol you should be able to easily run DDS within a distributed environment

Comment: Enable DCPS (called also DDS-I) as wire protocol and just let discovery do the job.

Comment: Can you give me basic steps needs to be followed to work DDS in distributed environment.

Comment: Nothing special has to be done, just create a small application and start publishing your data, in another app receive it, when you have DDS-I configured as protocol all works out of the box